# VSeWSS "Attach to IIS Worker Processes" grayed out

Tags: sharepoint, vsewss

This is a repost from the [msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/f4e47c06-2c3e-4dd2-9591-f6195ae52732) that got no good results.

In VSeWSS 1.3 on VS 2008, the "Attach to IIS Worker Processes" seems to always be grayed out (Build -> Quick Deploy Solution).

This forces me to run iisapp from the command line, note the PID of my w3wp process, hit Ctrl-Alt-P in VS to bring up the Attach to Process dialog, sort by PID, locate the PID i obtained earlier, and hit ok.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can skip getting the PID.  I just select all the w3wp processes and attach to them all.

Comment: I see that when I do select "Attach to IIS Worker Processes", VS attaches to all w3wp processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the "Attach to worker process" to not be grayed out, I have to select the project node in solution explorer.  (This is the only project in this solution.)  If I select a sub-folder or file the option is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I run into the same issue when I have multiple instances of w3wp running (which is obviously going to be the case if you are hosting Central Admin and your SSP in seperate app pools.)  I recommend just closing all w3wp processes that aren't executing the code you are attempting to debug; close VS, reset IIS, open VS and try again.